# sliding up panel - thin line sliding panel under google mapfragment

Tags: android, android-framelayout, slidingmenu, slidingpanelayout

I made slidinguppanel using this repository https://github.com/dlukashev/AndroidSlidingUpPanel-foursquare-map-demo

However, it contains one bug which is not covered anywhere.

When I touch anywhere to expand panel (listview) works well, but while I'm trying to expand it by holding a top of a list view (blue line on screen2) panel hide under the map (framelayout) (screen3)

How it's even possible that this blue line hiding panel under mapfragment and rest of listview expand it well?

Any ideas why? Please give me just a hint how to fix it?

Please look at the screen:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G88Ok.jpg]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <org.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        android:id="@+id/slidingLayout"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:shadowHeight="0dp"
        app:paralaxOffset="@dimen/paralax_offset"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="497dp"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/slidingContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/transparentView"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/map_height"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_height"
                android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/transparentView"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </org.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you hide panel???

Comment: I need some help.. I saw that code but I did't get to hide the scroll panel.. I want that to hide the panel.. and when app is run it will show from bottom just one line of listview??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override ListView

```
public class LockableListView extends ListView {

private boolean mScrollable = true;

public LockableListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public LockableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public LockableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mScrollable = enabled;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // if we can scroll pass the event to the superclass
            if (mScrollable) {
                return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            }
            // only continue to handle the touch event if scrolling enabled
            return mScrollable; // mScrollable is always false at this point
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Don't do anything with intercepted touch events if
    // we are not scrollable
    if (!mScrollable) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

}

Then put disable scrolling when needed

```
private void collapseMap() {
    mSpaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mTransparentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (mMap != null && mLocation != null) {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLocation, 11f), 1000, null);
    }
    mListView.setScrollingEnabled(true);
}

private void expandMap() {
    mSpaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mTransparentView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14f), 1000, null);
    }
    mListView.setScrollingEnabled(false);
}
```

I pushed this changes to GitHub https://github.com/dlukashev/AndroidSlidingUpPanel-foursquare-map-demo/commit/7b869394e9d197e6f56a833804426577dcb8458a

Enjoy

Comment: Thank you so much for your remarkable help! Problem fixed!